promise never exist pending state
I have hosted my backend on Render. When I try to reach the /login endpoint via https://hotel-website-1-9mlw.onrender.com/api/login, the promise remains in a pending state.
routes
import { Router } from "express";
const router = Router();
import {
    register,
    login,
    logout,
    refreshToken
} from "../controllers/auth.js";


router.route('/logout').post(logout);
router.route('/login').post(login)
router.route('/register').post(register);
router.route('/refresh').get(refreshToken);

export default router 


Controller
const login = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("login function");
    try {
        console.log("login function in the backend  is called ")
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const foundUser = await Users.findOne({ email });

        if(email.length == 0 || password.length ==0) return res.sendStatus(404)// credentials missing
        if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(401) // unauthorized


        // evaluate password

        const match = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, foundUser.password);
        if (match) {
            console.log("it matched")
            // create jwt token
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
                { "username": foundUser.username }, // payload
                process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                { expiresIn: '30s' }
            )
            const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
                { "username": foundUser.username }, // payload
                process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, // secret 
                { expiresIn: '1d' } // expire date
            );
            await Users.findOneAndUpdate(
                { email: foundUser.email }, // filter 
                { refreshToken: refreshToken }, // update
                { new: true } // return updated value
            )
            res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }) // 1 day in milliseconds 
                .status(200)
                .json({ 'accessToken': accessToken, 'username': foundUser.username, 'email': foundUser.email });

            
        }
        else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
           
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
       
    }
}

I have hosted my backend on Render. When I try to reach the /login endpoint via https://hotel-website-1-9mlw.onrender.com/api/login, the promise remains in a pending state.
To check where the problem lies, I tried to reach the /register endpoint via https://hotel-website-1-9mlw.onrender.com/api/register, and I got the desired output.
I also tried to reach the /login endpoint during development via http://localhost:8000/api/login, and I got the desired output.
"I am not able to understand where the problem lies. The login function is correct because I get the desired output when I hit http://localhost:8000/api/login, and the backend is correctly hosted on Render because when I try to hit the /register endpoint, I get the desired output.
